# How to separate values that contain a substring into separate arrays in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm probably not going to do to good of job at asking this question but I have a JSON array that I parse to pull time values in this format:

(2020-01-08T20:00:03.492Z)

I want to separate unique times by date. Therefore, I split the strings in a for loop using substring at the index of 'T' and create a new array and then filter it to only include unique values such as this:

Array(6) [ "2020-01-10", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-06", "2019-12-23", "2019-12-17" ]

I now want to take each of those values, correlate it to the original output of the JSON response to pull a different field 'vulnerabilitiesCount' containing the number of vulnerabilities for the specified date and add those values for each date in the array above. I have no idea how to go about this to loop through each index in the unique array. The below code does what I want to achieve for the first index of the array. Appreciate any input in advance!

```
        let arrTwo = [];
        let arrThree = [];
        for(var i=0; i<jsonP.length; i++)
        {
          var jtStr = jsonP[i].time
          // for(b in unique){
            var j = jtStr.includes(unique[0]);
            if(j === true){
              arrTwo.push(jtStr);
            }                
            for(var d=0;d<=arrTwo.length;d++){
              if(arrTwo[d]==jsonP[i].time){
                arrThree.push(jsonP[i].vulnerabilitiesCount);
              }
            }
        // }
        }            
        var sum = 0;
        for(f=0;f<=arrThree.length;f++){
          sum += parseInt(arrThree[f]);
        }
```

Comment: How do you know what are the vulnerabilities of those dates? Are you matching it with another array or some regex?

Comment: I just need the vulnerability count which is another field in the same JSON array that contains the time field.

Comment: Do you need it in another array? or do you want to create an array with it?

Answer (score 0):

Taking in mind that your JSON is similar to the one I used for my code, it should be something like this:

```
const data = {
  time: ["(2020-01-08T20:00:03.492Z)"],
  vulnerabilitiesCount: [1, 2]
}

let timesArray = [];

for(let i = 0; i < data.time.length; i++) {
  let formTime = data.time[i].replace("(", "");
  formTime = formTime.replace(")", "");

  let parsedTime = new Date(formTime);

  let month = parsedTime.getMonth()+1;
  if(month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }

  let timeFormatted = parsedTime.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + parsedTime.getDate();

  let fullTime = {
    time: "",
    vulnerabilitiesCount: 0 
  }

  if(timesArray.find(t => t.time == parsedTime)) {
    continue;
  }

  fullTime.time = timeFormatted;
  if(data.vulnerabilitiesCount[i] > 0) fullTime.vulnerabilitiesCount = data.vulnerabilitiesCount[i];

  timesArray.push(fullTime)
}
```

Hope this helps.